# Heroku web dynos often slowing down but never getting more than 20% load?

Tags: performance, heroku, newrelic

A couple of times a day we see the response time of any one of our Heroku web dynos increase tremendously. We have been analyzing this with little success so far.

One strange thing we see, however, is the following. Look at this "Instances running" graph from New Relic:
[image: Heoku instances running]

You see that we've played around with the number of web dyno's, but the majority of the time we have had 2 dynos with 4 Unicorn processes each. But never ever do these instances seem to get the "full load". How should we interpret this? Is this just that at any time the sum of CPU usage of all instances never exceeds approx. 20%? And if so, it seems we're really underutilizing our dynos. What can we optimize here?

For clarity: the average memory usage is constant between 110MB and 120MB, so that does not seem to be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://news.rapgenius.com/James-somers-herokus-ugly-secret-lyrics ?

Heroku has worked on addressing this, but you'll need to talk to them for further recommendations.

Comment: Yeah, I read that one. But it still does not explain the -what it seems- 80% underutilization of available CPU capacity. Maybe I should raise a ticket at Heroku, but I thought I'd first check the community here.

Comment: Yeah, ask Heroku about this.  New Relic is just reporting what Heroku is doing.